# Different UI for different API's

Tags: android, google-play

I am looking for a way to get different UI design for different API's. Google search gave me a link:http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CreatingApks

In this link it states it is better to create different Apk's for different API and play store will take care of choosing the best one for the phone.

Is this the only method or is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thats possible if you are ready to write more code,

One thing you can do if you want it to achieve different API levels with different UI is to detect API level runtime by using this constant: [`android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT). It returns one of [these values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

Now according to this version you can have different `layout xml` to be set as **contentView** of your activity.

**Note** : This has more maintenance hazard. In case you want to add/remove any UI element you have to modify all of your layout XMLs in your application.

Comment: Doing this is HARD and NOT RECOMMENDED. There is a MUCH simpler way of achieving this, by letting the platform do it for you. An example would be this, but you can also do the same for any resource you want (put the resources in -vX folders, like layout-v11, meaning that folder will be used for API levels higher than 11): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme . OR see Muz's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to build multiple APKs to achieve this.

Look into the links at: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use different APKs if at all possible; it creates a mess.

To use a specific layout for API 14, for example, use the folder `/res/layout-v14` instead of `/res/layout`. `/res/layout-v8` for API 8, and so on…

Android will take resources from the folder that most closely matches it. The folders act as sort of a requirement. So, if you have API 15 and no `layout-v15` folder, it will take it from `layout-v14`. If you have `layout-v14` and `layout-v8`, if it's using API 10, it will use `layout-v8`.